# Is there a download for JBoss AS 7 Web Profile?

Tags: jboss

On the [official downloads page](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) I can only find the *Java EE 6 Full Profile* for 7.1, the *Web Profile* is only available for 7.0. Is there any place where I can download the *Web Profile* for 7.1? If not, why is there no such distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You can found the code in github and compile it, try:

```
github clone git://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as.git
```

Or you can just [download the binaries](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-web/7.1.1.Final).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.